# how to get facebook page id from url

Tags: facebook

I need to get page id from location uri
I try to do it this way

```
fetch(https://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.facebook.com/pages/category/Butcher-Shop/The-Butcher-Shop-Grill-Arabia-699673637068327/ fields=access_token& access_token=my_token)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(data => console.log(data));
```

I got an error "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details."

As I understand I can use this endpoint only after app review??? is there another way???
How I am going to use api in general, I have some locations page urls, from this urls I am going to get page id, than user after he get his token using page id and token can get page reviews, it's the main goal

Comment: if you use user login anyway, just read his pages with /me/accounts?fields=id,access_token and then get the page reviews for his pages. no need to turn urls into page ids.

Comment: the problem is that user can have more than one pages, and i don't know what page i need

Comment: let him choose the page then, right after getting all his pages with /me/accounts

Comment: thanks a lot, I think it's a move to right direction, but have one more problem, unfortunately, cant insert screenshort, when I make a request to get page reviews I can't get reviewer and rating field, the message is "Field is empty or disallowed by access token" but I am sure reviewer filed is not empty